# Archiving a message twice in Apple Mail (Exchange) sends it to where?

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks, apple-mail

My organization uses Exchange Server 2010. I am using Mail (7.0) on OS X Mavericks (10.9).

After right-clicking a message in my inbox (or any other folder) and then selecting Archive, the message goes to the Archive folder that I created in my Exchange account. If I right-click the message again (already in the Archive folder), I can select Archive again. I did this, and the message disappeared.

It seems to have deleted the message and expunged it immediately, because I can not find the message in any other folder (or Trash, Junk, etc.) Can anyone confirm this behavior or explain what is actually happening when I perform the described actions?

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm the behaviour but not explain it! I have an IMAP account set up in Mail. If I archive a message it moves the message to the Archive folder. Archiving the message again seems to delete it with no trace (although you can undo the action).

This doesn't seem like very desirable behaviour to me, maybe a bug?

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Are you using the same version of Mail.app?

Comment: Yes, Mail 7 on Mavericks.